# Writing own HTTP server

Tags: architecture, httpserver

I'm planning to write an HTTP Server:

There will be two modules (L & P), both executables.

One of those executables (L) will be listening to HTTP request and will simply forward it to other executable (P) which has all HTTP parsing logic and do further stuff. There may be number of 'Ps' whose connection info/params will be known to listener L.

Idea is if one of the Ps crashes other can be used etc. Moreover, one P can be run to interact with one copy of DB and other Ps with other replica.

Now, I'm confused if I go for L&Ps combo or only with L which will listen, recv, parse the request and respond.

`In case I go for L&P combo there will be some overhead because of request forwarded from L to P and then response from P to L.`

- Can this overhead be neglected for 100,000 hits per second?

Comment: Anything can handle 100,000 hits per second if you throw enough hardware at it.

Comment: Umm, where's the question here? because I don't see the question mark anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, what's wrong with all existing web servers? Why not create a module to one of those?

If you want to go ahead and create your own one (and it's not a trivial task if you want to support the HTTP standard fully): Create a HTTP server and modules (.so/.dll). Simply wrap all module calls with try/catch to prevent them from crashing your server.

Another way to do it is to create a http parser lib and let all P's be be complete web servers and put a proxy / load balancer in front them. In this way you can move any of the Ps to new servers if you run out of processing power.

Comment: I'm talking about the second approach of your suggestions. The L would behave as load balancer. From "`P` will have parsing logic", I meant the http parser library will be loaded by `P`. Moreover, I'm not planning to support full HTTP standard. Majorly, GET, POST and multipart/form-data